# Haskell: what does this method do

Tags: haskell, semantics

In my test-exam a question was, what this method does.

`dos a = ([x | x <- [2..div a 2], mod a x == 0] == [])`

I am new to Haskell but as far as I can say, it checks if the result of `dos a = ([x | x <- [2..div a 2], mod a x == 0])` is an empty list. Also x are all numbers of `a` divided by 2 which have %number == 0. Thus this are all even numbers? It seems like it checks if the number is dividable through 2, if yes -> false, else otherwise. Could anyone explain to me the semantic in detail?

Comment: the best way to find out is to break the expression in multiple functions, and evaluate them in a REPL. `[2..div a 2]` returns the list of integers from 2 to a/2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are close to what is going on. There are several components to understand.

First, `[2 .. div a 2]` generates a list of numbers from 2 to `floor(a / 2)`.

Next, `mod a x == 0` filters out the values from 2 to `floor(a / 2)` which
divide `a` (e.g. it finds all the factors of `a`).
Thus, the list generated by

```
[x | x <- [2 .. div a 2], mod a x == 0]
```

contains all the numbers that divide `a`.

Finally, the `== []` checks that
this list is empty (e.g. `a` has no factors). So, what this function actually
does is to determine whether or not a number is prime by attempting to
generate its factors, which is easy to see when you use `dos` as the predicate
for filter:

```
Prelude> let dos a = ([x | x <- [2..div a 2], mod a x == 0] == [])
Prelude> :t dos
dos :: Integral t => t -> Bool
Prelude> filter dos [2 .. 100]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97] -- Prime goodness
```

Answer (score 6):

It is the basic algorithm to check if a number is prime or not. It traverses over all the numbers from `2` to `a/2` and checks if any of it divides `a`, if the list is empty then it means it has no factors between `2` and `a/2` which implies the number is prime.

Comment: This algorithm is *bad*. One needs to check only if the number is divisible by **primes** whose square is not greater than the number.

Comment: @Ingo I am not saying anything about the algorithm. It was the question asked in his exam, so I am just explaining what it does. You just can't answer a question in exam saying "your algorithm is not optimal so I will not answer this question".

Comment: I know, I just wanted to mention it, lest anybody thinks this is anythik but a silly homework question algorithm.